# Order of growth of functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove whether there exists a $\beta$ such that $n^p = \omega(\beta^n)$ (i.e. $n^p$ grows faster than $\beta^n$) I have attached an image of my work and I don't know what to do from there.

[image: .]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it since
$b^n$ grows faster than $n^p$ for any
$p > 0, b > 1$.

To see this, take the log of each.

$\log(b^n) = n \log(b)$
and
$\log(n^p) = p\log(n)$.

Since
$\dfrac{\log(n)}{n}
\to 0$,
$p\log(n)-n\log(b)
\to -\infty$,
so
$\dfrac{n^p}{b^n}
\to 0$.